Android Camera2 image capture is black and live stream stops
I'm currently learning Android. My current task depends on the following steps:

Continuously stream the camera image to a SurfaceView
When pressing a button, capture an image and upload it to a local server

This is my main activity layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/upload_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Upload Image" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

This is my MainActivity.kt code:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var cameraPreview: SurfaceView
    private lateinit var uploadButton: Button

    private var cameraDevice: CameraDevice? = null
    private var cameraId: String? = null
    private var cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession? = null
    private val cameraManager: CameraManager by lazy {
        getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    }

    private val cameraCallback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice = camera
            createCameraPreviewSession()
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
            camera.close()
            cameraDevice = null
        }

        override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
            onDisconnected(camera)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        cameraPreview = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview)
        uploadButton = findViewById(R.id.upload_button)

        requestPermission()

        cameraPreview.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
            override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                openCamera()
            }

            override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {}

            override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                cameraDevice?.close()
            }
        })

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener {
            takePicture(this@MainActivity) { base64Image ->
                if (base64Image != null) {
                    uploadImageToServer(base64Image)
                } else {
                    Timber.e("Failed to capture or convert image.")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            ),
            1
        )
    }

    private fun openCamera() {
        val cameraIdList = cameraManager.cameraIdList
        if (cameraIdList.isEmpty()) return

        cameraId = cameraIdList[0]

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId!!, cameraCallback, null)
        }
    }

    private fun createCameraPreviewSession() {
        try {
            val surface = cameraPreview.holder.surface
            val captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice?.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
            captureRequestBuilder?.addTarget(surface)

            val outputConfig = OutputConfiguration(surface)
            val sessionConfiguration = SessionConfiguration(
                SessionConfiguration.SESSION_REGULAR,
                listOf(outputConfig),
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        cameraCaptureSession = session
                        captureRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO)
                        cameraCaptureSession?.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder?.build()!!, null, null)
                    }

                    override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    }
                })

            cameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(sessionConfiguration)
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun takePicture(activity: Activity, callback: (String?) -> Unit) {
        val imageFileName = "jiggi"
        val storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir)

        val captureCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)

                FileOutputStream(imageFile).use { outputStream ->
                    cameraPreview.drawToBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
                }

                convertImageToBase64(imageFile.absolutePath)?.let {
                    callback(it)
                    imageFile.delete()
                } ?: run {
                    Timber.e("Failed to convert image to Base64.")
                    callback(null)
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            val captureBuilder = cameraDevice?.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)?.apply {
                addTarget(cameraPreview.holder.surface)
                set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)
                set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0)
            }

            val captureSession = cameraCaptureSession ?: return
            captureSession.stopRepeating()
            captureSession.capture(captureBuilder!!.build(), captureCallback, null)
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun convertImageToBase64(absoluteFilePath: String): String? {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absoluteFilePath)
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)

        val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

        return "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }

    private fun uploadImageToServer(base64Image: String) {
        val serverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:3100/upload"

        Thread {
            try {
                val url = URL(serverUrl)
                val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

                connection.requestMethod = "POST"
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
                connection.doOutput = true

                jsonObject.put("image", base64Image)

                val outputStreamWriter = OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream)

                outputStreamWriter.write(jsonObject.toString())
                outputStreamWriter.flush()

                val responseCode = connection.responseCode
                val responseMessage = connection.responseMessage

                if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Timber.d("$responseCode: $responseMessage")
                }

                outputStreamWriter.close()
                connection.disconnect()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }.start()
    }
}

The idea is to obtain the current camera. If a special thing comes up, the user needs to press the upload button. The stream should continue to stream but when he presses the button, the current stream should be captured and stored as image. If this is done, I read the image, transform it to a base64 image string and provide it to the REST API.
Somehow, the image stays black. I've tried so many things but I can not find the issue. Also, when I press the upload button, my live stream of the camera freezes. If I press the button again, it refreshes and freezes again.
I would be so glad for any advice since I'm relatively new to Android development.
